# Calling Range method inside MsgBox Error

Tags: excel, vba, methods

How come this works:

```
Sub testsub()
myRange = Range("A1:A5").Address

MsgBox myRange

End Sub
```

but this throws RunTime '424' Object required?

```
Sub testsub()
myRange = Range("A1:A5")

MsgBox myRange.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: i don't understand why you need myRange.
MsgBox Range("A1:A5").Address works fine for me.

Comment: if you need to save the range, you might want to do this: First declare the variable: `Dim rg As Range`, then safe the range: `Set rg = Range("A1","A5")`. Then call the MsgBox: `MsgBox rg.Address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Object* references are meant to be created with the `set` command, so changing your second example as follows will work:

```
set myRange = Range("A1:A5")
MsgBox myRange.Address
```

So the question you *should* be asking is not so much why it doesn't work in your second example, but why it *does* work in the first.

I believe that's because you're never actually attempting to store an *object* there. Instead you're *using* a range object to get access to the `Address` property, and that's a string (one of the VBA fundamental data types) rather than an object.